# Start text search from focus point in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, search, find

In chrome, when I start typing for a text search, it searches from the beginning of the document rather than from where I am looking in the document. Is there a way to do the latter? (currently I have to click on some text where I'm currently at to make that happen)

Edit: To clarify, it's not just me being lazy at having to click the button -- many times I forget to click and then the focus changes to a completely different part of the document and then I have to find the part I was reading again which can get incredibly annoying.

Comment: You have to click on some text and that's too much for you? How much easier would you expect to be able to get it? Are you looking for a button? Those need to be clicked too you know?

Comment: Many times I forget to click and then the focus changes to a completely different part of the document and then I have to find the part I was reading again. And what if I can't click on there relevant text -- many times they happen to be links. I don't see what's so wrong about trying to make things a little bit easier...isn't this supposed to be superuser?

Comment: And I'm not looking for a button -- I was wondering if there was a setting in chrome that I could change.

Comment: Nothing wrong with asking, I just usually prefer to search starting from the start of a document. I think that if you had it search from current part of document, by default, that you wouldn't like it as much as you think you might.